# Recognise Swedish characters with ctype_alpha?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm trying to match a string (including Swedish characters) using PHP's ctype_alpha function. It doesn't recognise the Swedish specific vowel characters, e.g.:

```
Å Ä Ö
```

I don't want to set locale to Swedish, so how can I make this work?

Comment: Try to set your location with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php And see if it works

Comment: That's what I don't want to do.

Comment: Then you won't get it to work, since if you read the manual it's says: *[A-Za-z]*

Comment: If you set the locale to Swedish doesn't that restrict your whole script to using Swedish characters?

Comment: No not everything is affected by setlocale()